# extract id from array using map with condition javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is an array of objects

```
  const groups = [
    { id: 0, name: "All", selected: false },
    { id: -1, name: "All", selected: true },
    { id: 1, name: "Group1", selected: false },
    { id: 2, name: "Group2", selected: false },
    { id: 3, name: "Group3", selected: false },
    { id: 4, name: "Group4", selected: true }
  ];
```

I want to extract ids from this object with map

```
groups.map(group => group.id > 0 && group.selected ? group.id:null)
```

but the result will be 
**[null,null,4,null...]**
actually it should be **[4]**

I know I can use another function like **forEach** and **push** or **map** and **filter** but I would solve it with one iteration with map or something else.

Comment: The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on **every element** in the calling array. That is why you are getting null for those fields which does not satisfies the condition. Instead use **filter**

Comment: @brk you mean there is no way to avoid returning value in map?

Comment: "_I want to bang this nail into a wall. I know I can use a hammer, but I want to use my shoe_". Do you see the problem? You're using the wrong tool for the job. Why do you think you need to use `map` specifically? It looks like a combination of `filter` and `map` is what you should be using as per one of the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the object/s under your criteria and then extract the id/s with a map

```js
const groups = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "All",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: -1,
    name: "All",
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Group1",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Group2",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Group3",
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Group4",
    selected: true
  }
];


const result = groups.filter(x => x.id > 0 && x.selected).map(x => x.id)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks @eugen-sunic , is there any way to avoid returning value in map.

Comment: the point of map is to return something to you array, what do you want exactly?

Comment: What I want and why I ask this question was to find a way to return nothing or void return value in some condition in map function.

Comment: but you are saying you don't want that `but the result will be [null,null,4,null...] actually it should be [4]`

Comment: @HamidShoja anyways if your issue is to use filter and achieve this with a map then that's not possible and should not be done that way either.. you should first filter and then extract otherwise you want something else

Comment: Ok thanks, so the map function always returns a value and it's unavoidable.

Comment: @HamidShoja that is not true. You can achieve a single pass with the transformations you desire if you use transducers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a transducer in this case, so that you will not iterate through the array 2 times.

```js
const groups = [
  { id: 0, name: "All", selected: false },
  { id: -1, name: "All", selected: true },
  { id: 1, name: "Group1", selected: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Group2", selected: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Group3", selected: false },
  { id: 4, name: "Group4", selected: true }
];

const filteredIds = groups.reduce(
  (ids, { id, selected }) => (
    id > 0 && selected ? [...ids, id] : ids
  ), []
);

console.log(filteredIds);
```

Comment: your solution certainly has the performance benefits of a transducer solution, but it is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element and extraction is not possible with this. Either use map() and then discard the array items or use filter().

Better approach would be using filter(). The filter() method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function).

`let result = groups.filter(x => x.id > 0 && x.selected).map(x => x.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in **one** iteration with transducers.

```js
const getPositiveSelectedIDs = pipe([
  filter(and([
    gt(get('id'), 0),
    get('selected'),
  ])),
  map(get('id')),
])

transform(getPositiveSelectedIDs, [])(groups) // => [4]
```

In this example, `getPositiveSelectedIDs` is a transducer we declared using functions `pipe`, `map`, and `filter`. The predicate passed to `filter` uses functions `and`, `gt`, and `get` to say

> only let groups through who have positive ids and who have been selected

then, without creating any intermediate arrays, we get the ids of each group with `map` and `get`. `getPositiveSelectedIDs` behaves as a transducer when we use it in `transform`. The flow of data starts when we call the transformation `transform(getPositiveSelectedIDs, [])` with `groups`.

[More on transducers](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#transducers)